# 301 redirection in CodeIgniter having ? issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, redirect

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|uploads|tt|application/modules/.*/assets|resources|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]    

Redirect 301 /testurl /home/
```

This is my `.htaccess` file for checking `301` redirection in my CodeIgniter project.

The `301` redirection works fine but problem is with the URL. When I try...

http://parcmobilenew.eworkdemo.com/testurl

...it redirects to Home Page as mentioned in `.htaccess` but it takes requested URL in query string like this...

http://parcmobilenew.eworkdemo.com/home?/testurl

How can I make the `.htaccess` not do this when redirecting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Don't mix `Redirect` rules with `mod_alias` ones.
- Keep redirect rules before internal rewrite ones.

You can use this code:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^testurl/?$ /home/? [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|uploads|tt|application/modules/.*/assets|resources|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Better to test in a new browser to avoid old 301 caches.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer , But i has to use 301 redirection instead of RewriteRule, this is sample I have problem for another project which need to map old URLs to new URL with 301 redirection

Comment: your code is working but it is direct Not using 301 redirection or it is Using 301 ?
I dont know exactly it is right for my requirement , please share your view I am confused

Comment: Even for mapping old URLs to new ones you can use 301 rules using `RewriteRule` as I showed. In any case keep `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]` as last rule.

Comment: Sir I have 300 different URLs which need to be map with new URL
Like 

Redirect 301 /blog/post/3568424 /blog/do-orgone-products-actually-harmonize-nuclear-radiation

Comment: 300 is not huge number, I have seen thousands of rule like that. Just follow my advise of keeping 301 **before** bottom rule.

Comment: okey sir , I am using 
RewriteRule ^blog/post/3568424/?$ /blog/do-orgone-products-actually-harmonize-nuclear-radiation/? [L,NC,R=301]
instead of my 
Redirect 301 /blog/post/3568424 /blog/do-orgone-products-actually-harmonize-nuclear-radiation
for each url give me 5-10 mins

Comment: Thanks Anubhava , it really worked, took little long time but its done